# d3js selection.each() callback group argument

Tags: d3.js

Simple html:

```
 <div class="div1">
      <div class="test"><span>1</span></div>
      <div class="test"><span>2</span></div>
 </div>
```

And js:

```
var el = d3.select(".div1").selectAll(".test");
el.each(function() { 
      console.log(arguments);
});
```

Output:

```
[undefined, 0, 0]
[undefined, 1, 0]
```

What is the latest argument (0)? According to source code this is group, but I can't find anything about selector groups in d3 documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's for nested selectors:
http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/

e.g. for this HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Let's select td:

```
var el = d3.selectAll("tr").selectAll("td");
```

el is `[
Array[2]
, 
Array[2]
]`

and `el.each`:

```
el.each(function() { 
    console.log('args',arguments);
});
```

Output:

```
args [undefined, 0, 0]
args [undefined, 1, 0]
args [undefined, 0, 1]
args [undefined, 1, 1]
```

Comment: +1 good answer. To expand a little, think of it as: `datum, i, j`, where `j` is the grouping. If there's only one group, the grouping is going to be 0.